# materialize disabled button not working on jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, button, materialize

, I'm triying to disable a button on materialize, when it's clicked....but it's not working for me, on the succes function on my ajax request it must add class disabled from this framework...but nothing happens, and the ajax request it's working fine!!...pls help!!

```
$(document).on('click', '.aprove , .disapprove', function() {
    if (sesion != "") {
        if ($(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop() == 'aprove_president') {

            var id = $(this).closest("div .col .s6").find('input[type=hidden]').attr('id');
            alert(id);
            var data = {

                'id_politic' : id,
                'sesion'     : sesion,
                'status'     : 1
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: baseurl+'result/aprove',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data
            })
            .done(function() {
                $(this).addClass('disabled');
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("complete");
            });

        }
        else if ($(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop() == 'disapprove_president') {

        }

    }
    else {
        $('#verification').openModal();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah !!! that's it !! thanks man ! pls post your answer , so I can select it as right !

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` in your `done` anonymous function is in different scope. Therefore, it's not your button.

You might want to do it like,

```
$(document).on('click', '.aprove , .disapprove', function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
```

And re-use it in your `done` like,

```
.done(function() {
   $btn.addClass('disabled');
})
```